# PyTorch is installed but not imported

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pytorch

I am trying to build PyTorch.
Reference site：https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch

but, When we performed unit test, The following error occur.

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/usr2/pytorch/test/testByteTensor.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/testByteTensor.py:2: in <module>
    import PyTorch
E   ImportError: No module named 'PyTorch'
__________________ ERROR collecting test/testDoubleTensor.py ___________________
```

I understand that PyTorch is not imported.
but It is confirmed that pytorch is installed.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

environment

```
ubuntu 16.04
python3.5
cuda9.2
```

Comment: check in which python you have installed pytorch . maybe you installed in python2

Comment: and why is pytorch spelled as `PyTorch`in your code ? the case of modules matter

Comment: @AlbinPaul
Probably installed on python 3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytorch
>>>

Comment: @AlbinPaul
i'm sorry
As you said, it was installed in python2.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you should do `import torch` instead of `import PyTorch`
Here is what's work for me: (I installed it using conda)

```
>>> import torch

>>> torch.version
>>> <module 'torch.version' from '/home/koke_cacao/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/version.py'>

>>> print(torch.__version__)
>>> 0.4.1.post2

>>> a = torch.FloatTensor(2,3)
>>> tensor([[-7.4368e-13,  3.0911e-41, -9.6122e-13],
    [ 3.0911e-41, -7.3734e-13,  3.0911e-41]])
```

Edit: The version works with no problem at all for me. But if you insist to perform the unit test, maybe other people can solve your problem.